# How to get number of rows since last peak Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get a rolling count of how many rows have been between the current row and the last peak. Example code:

```
Value | Rows since Peak
-----------------------
   1       0
   3       0
   1       1
   2       2
   1       3
   4       0
   6       0
   5       1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the values to the `cummax` and use it for a `groupby.cumcount`:

```
df['Rows since Peak'] = (df.groupby(df['Value'].eq(df['Value'].cummax())
                                    .cumsum())
                           .cumcount()
                          )
```

How it works:

Every time a value is equal to the cumulated max (`df['Value'].eq(df['Value'].cummax())`) we start a new group (using `cumsum` to define the group). Then `cumcount` enumerates since the start of the group.

output:

```
   Value  Rows since Peak
0      1                0
1      3                0
2      1                1
3      2                2
4      1                3
5      4                0
6      6                0
7      5                1
```